How to run tt (t4) templates in vite project Visual Studio
I am using Visual Studio 2022. I have vite "react client" project in my solution. I also have a C# project with business logic. Previously I used .tt templates in react client project freely, but I can't find way to do that in the vite project.
Please suggest a way to use .tt templates in vite "react client" project in Visual Studio 2022.


Use the C# project in your Visual Studio solution to generate the .tt
templates.
Use a post-build step to copy the generated files from the
C# project to your Vite React client.
Import and use those generated files in your React components.


Yes this is an option. But is there a way to implement this direcly in vite project? Becouse vite project (react client) is only the reason why c# enums transformed to js is created.

If you want to directly integrate the enum transformation in your Vite project, a custom Node.js script or Vite plugin is a practical solution.

Is .net reflection or Roslyn (and .net projects) can be accessed from node.js script?

No, but you can try one of the following hybrid solutions.
-Run a .NET console app using Node.js’s child_process.
-Use Edge.js to run .NET code directly within a Node.js script.
-Use HTTP or gRPC communication between Node.js and a .NET Web API to process C# code and send back transformed JavaScript.
